# TFS Checking Out Two (Versioned) Projects Simultaneously

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, dependency-management

I have an application in TFS that is dependant on a "Common" library that is regularly updated. I'd like to make it so when I checkout the project, it checks out the common library at the same time (for all of the project's participants).

The closest analogy I can think of for this process is SVN's externals. I've done some research on my own to try and determine TFS's counterpart but from what I can find, one does not exist. Visual Studio's Git plugin does not appear to be able to support submodules as well. NuGET is a little bit too complicated for my needs.

So, *is there any out of the box mechanic for this in TFS's versioning software?*

Comment: What do you use for version control: TFVC or Git?

Comment: @GiulioVian I am currently using TFVC but I'd be open to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a workspace that contains the 2 projects. Select the workspace in the drop down menu, right click the root node of your  source control tree and select get latest. This will sync both projects as they are below root

Comment: This sounds like it would not tie them together for anyone else checking them out. Can you verify this is not just local (for only my machine)?

Comment: Your question specified 'I', you could setup this workspace on each users machine, depending on how you are set up you could share the workspace through team utilities. An alternative would be to add a .bat file with calls to checkout / get latest on the specific folders you require, store this in source control and then double click on the bat file to perform the operation

Comment: I've clarified that in the original question, sorry for the ambiguity. I do not think team utilities would work, we are just using the free TFS for now so I don't really have control over that. I will look into using a .BAT script, I think that would be the most viable option because you can have VS run a script pre-compilation.